# Unable to move picture to a files after upload in php

Tags: php

I am trying to move a picture to a file call upload , but I insert the data in the database the picture is not uploading in the file upload

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblrecruiter 
                        (Company_Name,Company_Desc,Phone_No,Tel_No,
                        Company_Pic,State_id,Address,Email,
                        Password,company_website_url)
            VALUES (:Company_Name,:Company_Desc,:Phone_No,:Tel_No,
                    :Company_Pic,:State_id,:Address,:Email,
                    :Password,:company_website_url)";
$filename= $_FILES['Company_Pic']['name'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
                ':Company_Name' => $_POST['txtcompanyName'],
                ':Company_Desc' => $_POST['textDesc'],
                ':Phone_No' => $_POST['txtphoneNum'],
                ':Tel_No' => $_POST['txttel'],
                ':Company_Pic' => $filename,
                ':State_id' => $_POST['txtstate'],
                ':Address' => $_POST['txtaddress'],
                ':Email' => $_POST['txtemail'],
                ':Password' =>$check,
                ':company_website_url' => $_POST['textcompanylink']));
              
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["Company_Pic"]["tmp_name"], "../mojob/upload" . $filename);
```

Comment: Ar you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your `<form>` tag? Please give us a more detailed explanation to help you.

Comment: Is it just a missing `/` in the `"../mojob/upload"`, if so try `"../mojob/upload/"`

Comment: Yes I have added it, but the problem still persist

Comment: _NOTE:_ May not be the issue now but it may well be later! Its never a good idea to use the `$_FILES['Company_Pic']['name'];` as the name of the file you will store on your disk. Lets assume thats a company logo, and everone calls that file `logo`

Comment: _Also_ Are you sure the file was actually uploaded? Check `$_FILES['Company_Pic']['error']`to be sure

Answer (score -2):

base on this code:

```php
<?php
error_reporting(0);
 
$msg = "";
 
// If upload button is clicked ...
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
 
    $filename = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["name"];
    $tempname = $_FILES["uploadfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $folder = "./image/" . $filename;
 
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
 
    // Get all the submitted data from the form
    $sql = "INSERT INTO image (filename) VALUES ('$filename')";
 
    // Execute query
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 
    // Now let's move the uploaded image into the folder: image
    if (move_uploaded_file($tempname, $folder)) {
        echo "<h3>  Image uploaded successfully!</h3>";
    } else {
        echo "<h3>  Failed to upload image!</h3>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Apart from all the other issues with this code, why would the OP want to convert a PDO based script to use MYSQLI_